# Python Recursion Backtracking Variable

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing some recursive function. Consider its prototype to be:

```
def path(a, row=0, col=0, weight=0, cumulative=[])
```

I am trying to find some path in the matrix `a`. The weight adds the values of that path so far and cumulative keeps track of the path.

At some point, this is invoked:

```
return path(a, row+1, col, weight, cumulative) + path(a, row+1, col+1, weight, cumulative)
```

Now the base case is as follows:

```
cumulative.append(a[row][col])
weight = weight + a[row][col]
return weight
```

which adds the current matrix element into cumulative, adds the weight and returns the weight. The problem is that each time `cumulative` calls append, it adds to the very same instance of `cumulative`. How can I ensure that each recursive stack frame takes a different copy of `cumulative`?

So when append is called in the base case, I want the value of cumulative called to be of the frame caller and not the previous recursive stack frame.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `cumulative = cumulative[:]`?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your whole function if you don't mind posting :)

Comment: One thing I'll point out in case you weren't aware. When a default parameter is set to a mutable value such as a list (e.g. `cumulative=[]`), that value is only initialized once when the function definition is read. That means any time you call `path` without specifying `cumulative`, the same list will be used.

Comment: Thanks Michael - yes I'm aware of that. mux below answered it. I needed a separate instance of cumulative for each frame. Apparently Python passes by reference (something I'm going to read about now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could call with a copy of cumulative:

```
return path(a, row+1, col, weight, list(cumulative)) + 
       path(a, row+1, col+1, weight, list(cumulative))
```